# 'float' object is not Iterable in Newton-Raphson iteration

Tags: python, iteration, newtons-method

I am getting a `'float' object is not Iterable` error in a script for Newton-Raphson iteration. I am applying the iteration to the function `f(x) = sin(x)`, and x<sub>0</sub> = 3 for the iteration. I am getting the error on the stopping condition, which is max{ |x<sub>n−2</sub> − x<sub>n−1</sub>|, |x<sub>n−1</sub> − x<sub>n</sub>| } < (1/2)10<sup>-9</sup>. Here is my code:

```
def NewtonRaphson2():
    L = []
    L.append(3)
    n = 0

    while(1):
        tmp = L[n] - (math.sin(L[n])/math.cos(L[n]))
        L.append(tmp)
        n+=1
        m = (max(abs(L[n-2] - L[n-1])), abs(L[n-1] - L[n]))
        if m < (.5e-9):
            print(n, "\n")
            x = max(abs(L[n-2] - L[n-1]), abs(L[n-1] - L[n]))
            print(x, "\n")
            print(L[n], "\n")
            break
        break
```

and the exact error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    NewtonRaphson2()
  File "C:/Python34/nmhw3.py", line 28, in NewtonRaphson2
    m = (max(abs(L[n-2] - L[n-1])), abs(L[n-1] - L[n]))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Does either the `max()` or `abs()` functions only take iterables? I am confused by this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple typo. Your parentheses close too early. It's in the line with the `m = ...`.

Basically what your code does is call `max` with just a single float. `max(x)`, however, doesn't make sense unless `x` is a list or an array.

Fix the parentheses and you're good.

Comment: Feeling foolish right about now.. Thanks for spotting that. Other replies in related posts were saying how certain functions do/dont play nice with iterables, so that's where my presumption came from

Comment: Glad to help out hehe. Years of programming and making exactly those types of mistakes gives one a keen eye for these typos.

If you liked the answer, you can mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

`max( )` can take either an *iterable* or multiple arguments.  This is shown in the first few lines of the `help(max)`:

```
>>> help(max)
Help on built-in function max in module builtins:

max(...)
    max(iterable, *[, default=obj, key=func]) -> value
    max(arg1, arg2, *args, *[, key=func]) -> value
```

as Lagerbaer points out - if you fix your parentheses placement you will invoke `max( )` with the second form - passing in multiple arguments.  (extra non PEP 8 spaces added for emphasis!)

```
m = max(   abs(L[n-2] - L[n-1])  ,   abs(L[n-1] - L[n])   )
```

If you *did* want to invoke `max( )` with the first form you could add parentheses to turn your two arguments into a single `tuple` which is then an  *iterable*.  The parentheses are superfluous but maybe you're a Lisp fan and miss all those parens! :-)

```
m = max( (  abs(L[n-2] - L[n-1])  ,   abs(L[n-1] - L[n]) )  )
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't even know python had a `help()` function